# Can we say Abraham was also sent to entire mankind till last prophet?

Tags: prophets, prophet-ibrahim

I am arriving at the conclusion that abraham was sent to entire mankind till time of last prophet except for specific nations like prophet Lut based on a hadith of bukhari. Zayd bin amr bin nufayl accepted religion of Abraham. Further moses and Jesus were sent to children of Israel. And no prophet arrived to arabs before last prophet except Ismail and ibrahim.

> Narrated Asma bint Abi Bakr (رضي الله عنها): I saw Zayd Ibn 'Amr Ibn Nufail standing with his back against the Ka'bah saying, **"O people of Quraish! By Allah, none amongst you is on the Religion of Ibrahim (عليه السلام) except me."** He used to preserve the lives of little girls: If somebody wanted to kill his daughter he would say to him, "Do not kill her for I will feed her on your behalf." So he would take her, and when she grew up nicely, he would say to her father, "Now if you want her, I will give her to you, and if you wish, I will feed her on your behalf." [Al-Bukhari: 3828].

Aditionally Prophets parents ending up in hellfire is because of their rejection of Religion of ibrahim

Comment: Maybe it would be good to note that Abraham is a direct ancestor of Muhammad and the reason Prophets parents ended up in hell fire was because a person changed the Religion of Ibrahim and they therefore started to worship idols and would therefore go to Hell but there was no one to guide them to the true religion until Muhammad SAWS came.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you asked the question, using the words "sent to" which is different than "acknowledged by". All prophets are prophets of Islam and therefore their prophecy is respected and honored by Muslims. The Quran states "Do not differentiate between any one of the prophets (and the others)." Or one could say it means do not consider one prophet as better than any other from your (our human) standpoint. Only Allah can differentiate between them. Therefore Islam is the religion of all prophets, and all prophets are "our" prophets of Islam. Refusal to acknowledge the prophecy of Prophet Ibrahim is therefore prohibited. He is also the "father of the prophets". But to envision a situation in which one must choose one prophet to follow, such as Ibrahim, as is this is to the exclusion of others, doesn't make sense here.

As for "sent to" — only Prophet Mohammad as the last and "seal" of the prophets, was "sent to" all mankind specifically and from the moment of his prophecy. All other prophets were sent to their respective nations (not a bordered concept as in modern times, one could say "a people"), which has to do with changes that occur in human development over time. For example, Allah lifted some of the restrictions Prophet Yaqoub imposed on himself, but that doesn't mean we reject the religion of Yaqoub, but simply that the basic faith is constant but the rules and other specifics may change. In that too is a lesson for those who ponder.